# can't get index of href element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write something to navigate with the arrow keys between all of the links within a container but for some reason I can't get the index of the href elements in #abc but I can in xyz with the same general code.

It comes up as 0 for any clicks in abc, why?

```
<div id="woot">
   <div id="xyz">
      <a href="#">x</a>
      <a href="#">y</a>
      <a href="#">z</a>
   </div>
   <div id="abc">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">b</a></li>      
         <li><a href="#">c</a></li>  
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#woot a').on('click', function() {
      var current = $("#woot a:focus").index();
      var length = $('#woot a').length;
      console.log("current index is: " + current + " total of: " + length);
   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s313buox/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It comes up as 0 for any clicks in abc, why?

**Reason:**

In `div#abc` under `ul` each `li` has only one child `a` element. So It will return 0 for every anchor element.

**Note:** `a` elements in `div#abc` are not direct child elements as like as in `div#xyz`.

**Update:**(for comment)

You should use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) in this way,

```
var current = $("#woot a").index($("a:focus"));//It will return the index based on this $("#woot a") collection(array) elements.
//var current = $("#woot a").index($(this));
```

Instead of this

```
var current = $("#woot a:focus").index(); //It will return the index considering its immediate parent.
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/s313buox/20/)

Comment: why does this matter if I'm focusing on the whole container's a elements and if the length of all of that is 6?

Comment: @totalnoob Check my **Update**

Answer (score 3):

You could get the index of the clicked `a` element based on a jQuery object containing all the descendant `a` elements. For instance, inside of the event listener, you could pass `this` as a parameter to the `.index()` method

```
$('#letters a').index(this);
```

In doing so, the index will be relative to the jQuery object `$('#letters a')` rather than the sibling elements (like in your example).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/055psc7s/)

```
$('#letters a').on('click', function(e) {
  var current = $('#letters a').index(this);
  var length = $('#letters a').length;
  console.log("current index is: " + current + " total of: " + length);
});
```

Since you're using `$('#letters a')` in three different places, you might as well store a reference to the jQuery object in a variable so that it doesn't have to be queried multiple times:

```
var $anchors = $('#letters a');
$anchors.on('click', function(e) {
  var current = $anchors.index(this);
  var length = $anchors.length;
  console.log("current index is: " + current + " total of: " + length);
});
```

As a side note, the indexes are zero-based, whereas the length of the jQuery object is not. This means that clicking on the last element would log:

> current index is: 5 total of: 6

You may want to take that into consideration by adding one to the index or subtracting one from the length.

Comment: Do you have any idea why my answer has been down-voted?

Comment: @JohnR I'm not sure. You provided a correct answer with an explanation and a demo.. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Yes. But you are the one who predicted the OP's need in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#woot a').on('click', function() {
var intCurrentIndex = $(this).index();
     var intLength = $('#woot a').length; console.log("current index is: " + intCurrentIndex + " total of: " + intLength); 
}); 
})
```